# Create categorical variable in R based on range

Tags: r, r-faq

I have a dataframe with a column of integers that I would like to use as a reference to make a new categorical variable.  I want to divide the variable into three groups and set the ranges myself (ie 0-5, 6-10, etc).  I tried `cut` but that divides the variable into groups based on a normal distribution and my data is right skewed.  I have also tried to use if/then statements but this outputs a true/false value and I would like to keep my original variable.  I am sure that there is a simple way to do this but I cannot seem to figure it out.  Any advice on a simple way to do this quickly?

I had something in mind like this:

```
x   x.range
3   0-5
4   0-5
6   6-10
12  11-15
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ian's answer (*cut*) is the most common way to do this, as far as i know.

I prefer to use ***shingle***, from the *Lattice* Package

the argument that specifies the binning intervals seems a little more intuitive to me.

you use *shingle* like so:

```
# mock some data
data = sample(0:40, 200, replace=T)

a = c(0, 5);b = c(5,9);c = c(9, 19);d = c(19, 33);e = c(33, 41)

my_bins = matrix(rbind(a, b, c, d, e), ncol=2)

# returns: (the binning intervals i've set)
        [,1] [,2]
 [1,]    0    5
 [2,]    5    9
 [3,]    9   19
 [4,]   19   33
 [5,]   33   41

shx = shingle(data, intervals=my_bins)

#'shx' at the interactive prompt will give you a nice frequency table:
# Intervals:
   min max count
1   0   5    23
2   5   9    17
3   9  19    56
4  19  33    76
5  33  41    46
```

Comment: Nice solution if you bother to set up a matrix of min and max values. This may be tedious if you have a dynamic range.

Comment: @ Roman, I was exactly thinking about that. I have a similiar problem buth with dynamic ranges. Do you have suggestions how to proceed in this case?

Answer (score 18):

```
x <- rnorm(100,10,10)
cut(x,c(-Inf,0,5,6,10,Inf))
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `smart_cut` from package `cutr`:

```
devtools::install_github("moodymudskipper/cutr")
library(cutr)

x <- c(3,4,6,12)
```

To cut with intervals of length 5 starting on 1 :

```
smart_cut(x,list(5,1),"width" , simplify=FALSE)
# [1] [1,6)   [1,6)   [6,11)  [11,16]
# Levels: [1,6) < [6,11) < [11,16]
```

To get exactly your requested output :

```
smart_cut(x,c(0,6,11,16), labels = ~paste0(.y[1],'-',.y[2]-1), simplify=FALSE, open_end = TRUE)
# [1]   0-5   0-5  6-10 11-15
# Levels:   0-5 <  6-10 < 11-15
```

[more on cutr and smart_cut](https://github.com/moodymudskipper/cutr)