# How do i create ranges dynamically in R?

Tags: r, range

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Create categorical variable in R based on range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647639/create-categorical-variable-in-r-based-on-range)

Given a range and number of intervals that are desired how do i create equal intervals in `R`. eg. If the range is between 1 and 100 and i want to create 10 intervals, I should get 1 - 10, 11 - 20, ..., 91 - 100.  Only this function should work for any range and any number of intervals.  If i have a range of 0 to 1 and number of intervals 30, then it should create the ranges such as 0 - 0.03, ..., 0.97 - 1, and so on.  The aim is to use these ranges to obtain values from a data.frame.

Comment: A simple search using `[r] range` will lead you to many examples of questions that are essentially identical.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you have

```
minVal<-0
maxVal<-1
numItv<-30
```

you can use

```
seq(minVal, maxVal, length.out=numItv+1)
```

to get the cutpoints for your intervals.

Answer (score 3):

See `?cut`. For your initial question:

```
cut(x,breaks=(0:10)*10)
```