# Create category based on range in R

Tags: r

I would like to add a column to my dataframe that contains categorical data based on numbers in another column.  I found a similar question at [Create categorical variable in R based on range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647639/create-categorical-variable-in-r-based-on-range), but the solution provided there didn't provide the solution that I need. Basically, I need a result like this:

```
x   group
3   0-5
4   0-5
6   6-10
12  > 10
```

The solutions suggested using `cut()` and `shingle()`, and while those are useful for dividing the data based on ranges, they do not create the new categorical column that I need.

I have also tried using something like (please don't laugh)

```
data$group <- "0-5"==data[data$x>0 & data$x<5, ]
```

but that of course didn't work.  Does anyone know how I might do this correctly?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Why didn't `cut` work? Did you not assign to a new column or something?

```
> data=data.frame(x=c(3,4,6,12))
> data$group = cut(data$x,c(0,5,10,15))
> data
   x   group
1  3   (0,5]
2  4   (0,5]
3  6  (5,10]
4 12 (10,15]
```

What you've created there is a `factor` object in a column of your data frame. The text displayed is the `levels` of the factor, and you can change them by assignment:

```
levels(data$group) = c("0-5","6-10",">10")
data
   x group
1  3   0-5
2  4   0-5
3  6  6-10
4 12   >10
```

Read some basic R docs on factors and you'll get it.

Comment: Spacedman -- thanks, your solution worked!  Indeed I did not assign a new column.  Do you know how I can get the categories to appear as "0-5" instead of "(0,5]"?

Comment: @Thomas use `labels` argument, try this `cut(data$x,c(0,5,10,15), labels=c("0-5", "6-10", ">10"))` and take a look at `?cut`, read the documentation.

Comment: Is there a way to change the class from logical to factor (so I can use this to group for plotting)? I've tried data$group <- factor(data$group), data$group <- as.factor(data$group), etc. but doesn't work.

Comment: Huh? It is a factor. Logical has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Note please dont just say "i tried X and it didn't work" - show us your code, what you expected, why you think you didnt get what you expected - and if necessary start a new question or edit this one.

Comment: Thanks Spacedman.  Sorry for the confusion.  I was getting an error when using this new "group" with some packages, but fixed it by by using "data$group". If I included "group" in my input data file, I didn't have to use this, which is why I was confused.  Also class(group) is logical whereas class(data$group) is a factor, which is why I was confused.  Thanks again for all of your help, I wouldn't have solved this without your assistance.