# Plotting intervals with barplot function R

Tags: r, bar-chart, intervals, lattice, bins

I am using the solution in this question to try to plot a bar plot with specified intervals:

[Create categorical variable in R based on range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647639/create-categorical-variable-in-r-based-on-range)

I created my intervals and tried to use them in the `barplot` function but I am obviously missing a step somewhere and I'm not sure how to get it to work. Here is my code and the error I am getting:

```
> library(lattice)

> a = c(0,10)
> b = c(11,20)
> c = c(21,30)
> d = c(31,40)
> e = c(41,50)
> f = c(51,60)
> g = c(61,70)
> h = c(71,80)
> i = c(81,90)
> j = c(91,100)
> k = c(101,120)
> l = c(121,150)
> m = c(151,200)
> n = c(201,500)
> o = c(501,3600)

> mybins = matrix(rbind(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o), ncol=2)
> shx <- shingle(data5$q3totalScleralLensesFit, intervals=mybins)
> shx
  Intervals:
  min  max count
  1    0   10   140
  2   11   20   117
  3   21   30    78
  4   31   40    31
  5   41   50    72
  6   51   60     5
  7   61   70     6
  8   71   80    28
  9   81   90     3
  10  91  100    49
  11 101  120     7
  12 121  150    28
  13 151  200    25
  14 201  500    61
  15 501 3600    28

> bp <- barplot(shx, main="", xlab="", ylim=c(0,160), ylab="", las=2, cex.names=0.75)

Error in barplot.default(shx, main = "", xlab = "", ylim = c(0, 160),  : 
'height' must be a vector or a matrix
```

I don't know how to fix the error. Is there an easier way to make bins like this for a barplot or does someone have any suggestions on how to make the intervals work with barplot?

Thank you!

Comment: you should probably use `cut` in this situation instead of `shingle`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't used the `shingle` function before, but it appears to be set up for creating a shingle plot, rather than a bar plot, although there may be a way that I'm not aware of to create a bar plot with a shingle object. In any case, the code below shows how to create a bar plot, using either base graphics, `lattice`, or `ggplot2`, but using the `cut` function to create the bins.

An issue to be aware of in terms of the error you received: `barplot` is a base graphics function. It's expecting a numeric vector of bar height values as its first argument. But `shx` is a shingle object, rather than a vector of heights, hence the error. In principle, someone could write a "shingle method" for `barplot` that would make `barplot` return a bar plot from a `shingle` object, but such a method doesn't at present exist and isn't necessary since there are other "standard" ways to create a bar plot.

As shown below, the way to plot a `shingle` object is by just calling the generic `plot` function, because `plot` "knows" that when it receives a `shingle` object, it should return a `lattice` shingle plot. If you run `methods(plot)` you'll see that `plot` has dozens of "methods" (including `plot.shingle`) that determine what `plot` does, depending on what type of object is fed to the `plot` function.

```
## Fake data
set.seed(5)
data5 = data.frame(q3totalScleralLensesFit = runif(1000,0,3600))

## Create shingle object

# Easier way to create bins
bins = c(0, seq(11,101,10),121,151,201,501,3601)
mybins = cbind(bins, lead(bins) - 1)[-length(bins),]

shx <- shingle(data5$q3totalScleralLensesFit, intervals=mybins)
```

#### Lattice shingle plot

```
plot(shx)
```

[image]

Now let's set up the data for creating a bar plot. We'll use the `cut` function:

```
# Create bins using cut function
data5$breaks = cut(data5$q3totalScleralLensesFit, 
                   breaks=c(seq(0,100,10),120,150,200,500,3600),
                   include.lowest=TRUE)
```

#### Base graphics bar plot

```
barplot(table(data5$breaks), horiz=TRUE, las=1)
```

[image]

#### `lattice` bar plot

```
barchart(data5$breaks)
```

[image]

#### `ggplot2` bar plot

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data5, aes(breaks)) +
  geom_bar() + 
  coord_flip() +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Wow. Awesome. I had no idea it was that simple. Thank you so much for the lengthy explanation and graphics.