# Collapsing groups in R plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using the WHO dataset in R and currently having trouble collapsing the age section into five groups  as seen in this picture.

[image]

I have pasted a copy of my code below, anything helps.

```
names(who) <- str_replace(names(who), "newrel", "new_rel")
who2 <- who %>%
  gather("codes", "case", 5:60) %>%
  select(-iso2, -iso3) %>%
  separate(codes, c("new", "type", "sexage"), sep = "_") %>%
  select(-new) %>%
  separate(sexage, into = c("sex", "age"), sep = 1,convert=TRUE)


who2 %>% 

    filter(!is.na(case)) %>% 

    group_by(year, sex, age) %>% 

    mutate(cases = sum(case)) %>%

  mutate(age = factor(age, levels=c("14","1524", "2534","3544","4554","5564","65"),ordered=TRUE)) %>% mutate(age = fct_recode(age, "0-14" = "14", "15-24" = "1524", "25-34" = "2534", "35-44" = "3544", "45-54" = "4554", "55-64" = "5564", "65+" = "65")) %>% 

ggplot() + 

  geom_line(mapping = aes(x = year, y = cases, color = age)) + 

facet_wrap(~sex)
```

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible example of the data? I see that you're following R for Data Science, so maybe there's a missing step

Comment: The data is from R. I initially transferred the data like so:                              
names(who) <- str_replace(names(who), "newrel", "new_rel")#newline
who2 <- who

Comment: I think you need to specify `group = age` within `aes()`. Not sure if that is the only issue.

Comment: OP, you need to share the entire code for how you converted `who` to `who2`.  You've given us only one of the lines.

Comment: Thiis is the rest of the code: names(who) <- str_replace(names(who), "newrel", "new_rel")
who2 <- who %>%
  gather("codes", "case", 5:60) %>%
  select(-iso2, -iso3) %>%
  separate(codes, c("new", "type", "sexage"), sep = "_") %>%
  select(-new) %>%
  separate(sexage, into = c("sex", "age"), sep = 1,convert=TRUE)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create categorical variable in R based on range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647639/create-categorical-variable-in-r-based-on-range)

Comment: and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5570293/add-column-which-contains-binned-values-of-an-integer-column and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6104836/splitting-a-continuous-variable-into-equal-sized-groups - check all linked threads, there are plenty. If this still doesn't help, please edit your question and tell us why not.